# regex doesn't match the word if it's not the last word

Tags: regex

i'm trying to write a regex which can match a word in a string with theese conditions:

1. the word must be 8 character length.
2. the word must has 1 alphabetic character at any position of the
   word.
3. the word must has 7 digits at any position of the word.

> `\b(?=\w{8}\z)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]{1})(?=(?:[\D]*[\d]){7}).*\b`

this can find `"123r1234"` and `"foo 123r1234"` but it doesn't find `"foo bar 123r1234 foo"`.
i tried to add word boundries but it didn't work.
what is wrong with my regex and how can i fix it?

thanks.

Comment: Try [`\b(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=(?:\D*\d){7})\w{8}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/lD5jB2/1)?

Comment: @stribizhev you're right :)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Then why posting others' suggestions? Can you explain what is wrong or what is not? Why remove this or that?

Comment: @user2859067: Does my suggestion work for you?

Comment: Do not use \z in your regex - "If you only want a match at the absolute very end of the string, use \z.". You would need edit your your regex, but \z is a reason why it matches only last words of the string.

Comment: @stribizhev yes it works. thanks. if you post it as an answer i'll approve it.

Comment: Posted. Thank you for integrity :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\b(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=(?:\D*\d){7})\w{8}\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD5jB2/1)

There several things to note here:

1. It is not necessary to enclose single shorthand classes (like `\d`) into character classes (pattern becomes too awkward and less readable). Thus, use `\D` instead of `[\D]`.
2. The rule of *number of look-aheads should equal the number of conditions - 1* (see [*Fine-Tuning: Removing One Condition* at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#n-1conds)). Most often, length restriction look-aheads with just 1 character/character class are valid candidates for being ported into the base pattern. Here, `(?=\w{8})` can easily replace `.*` at the end.
3. The `(?=\w{8}\z)` look-ahead contains an end-of-string `\z` anchor that forces a match at the end of the string, while you need (as now I know) the end of a *word*.
4. `[a-zA-Z]{1}` is equal to `[a-zA-Z]` since `{1}` means *exactly one repetition, and it is redundant (again, regex patterns should be as clean and concise as they can be).

**UPDATE** (+1 goes to @Jonny5)

There is another way of approaching the current problem: by having the word contain 8 word characters, but matching only 1 letter enclosed with any number of digits. This can be achieved with

```
(?i)\b(?=\w{8}\b)\d*[a-z]\d*\b
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD5jB2/2) (Note `i` modifier is used here)

Comment: I think you could even [shorten this down to this](https://regex101.com/r/bX6rK8/2): `\b(?=\w{8}\b)\d*[A-Za-z]\d*\b`

Comment: @Jonny5: Don't you discard the *the word must has 7 digits at any position of the word* condition? I agree we can shorten the regex with `i` modifier: `(?i)\b(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=(?:\D*\d){7})\w{8}\b` or `/\b(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=(?:\D*\d){7})\w{8}\b/i`.

Comment: Mine requires 8 word characters which consist of one `[A-Za-z]` and rest digits to meet word boundary.

Comment: @Jonny5: I see, it is using an opposite logic of excluding conditions. Yes, should work, too. Do you think I should add it, or will you post it as an alternative solution?

Comment: The problems were explained detailed in your answer. I'll be proud if you added it, won't post.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove last asterisk and change it by the 8 counter.

`\b(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=(?:[\D]*[\d]){7})\w{8}\b`

You can view it running here:

https://regex101.com/r/bX6rK8/1

Comment: The explanation *last asterisk and change it by the 8 counter* is not appropriate as it is not the reason why OP's regex failed.